# Is there a way to force-reinstall OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion?

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion

I had upgraded to 10.8.2 a few months ago and now, when trying to install some python modules, have messed up my default python installation on the Mac. I was wondering if there was a way to re-update to 10.8.2?

I downloaded the update again from the App Store but didn't not find an option to install ("reinstall") the update that I had downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reinstall OS X by reinstalling an update.

You will need to [boot into Recovery mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) by holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> during startup.

Through the Recovery System, you can then reinstall OS X via an Internet download. After that—or even during the download, I'm not sure—OS X will also apply all missing updates.

Depending on what exactly you did, there might even be no need to reinstall OS X completely. Of course, restoring from your Time Machine backup would also be a solution here. I can't imagine that installing Python modules could have caused any major troubles, unless you were playing around with `sudo`.